# How could a race condition cause p[0] to be None here?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ctypes, python-multithreading

Here's my (rather lengthy) function:

```
def go(self, target, outfile, infile, stderr=sys.stderr, timeout=None):        

    self.pre_proc_started()                                                    
    try:                                                                       
        infile_fileno = infile.fileno()                                        
    except AttributeError:                                                     
        infile_fileno = None                                                   
    p_stdin = infile if infile_fileno is not None else subprocess.PIPE         

    if timeout is not None:                                                    
        p = [None]                                                             
        def kill_process(p):                                                   
            if p[0]:                                                           
                p[0].kill()                                                    
            else:                                                              
                print("WTH")                                                   
        timer = threading.Timer(timeout, lambda: kill_process(p))              
        timer.start()                                                          

    p[0] = subprocess.Popen(target, stdin=p_stdin, stderr=stderr,              
                            env={'__AFL_SHM_ID': str(self.shm_id)})            
    try:                                                                       
        if p_stdin == subprocess.PIPE:                                         
            p[0].stdin.write(infile.read())                                    
            p[0].stdin.close()                                                 
    except IOError:  # brobably broken pipe                                    
        raise                                                                  
    p[0].wait()                                                                
    if timeout is not None:                                                    
        timer.cancel()                                                         
    self.post_proc_started()                                                   

    trace_bytes_addr = shmat(self.shm_id, 0, 0)                                
    if trace_bytes_addr == 2**64 - 1:                                          
        raise RuntimeError("shmat() failed (%s)" % os.strerror(errno()))       
    trace_bytes = ctypes.string_at(ctypes.c_void_p(trace_bytes_addr),          
                                   MAP_SIZE)                                   
    return trace_bytes
```

Why I find it hard to believe, if I run it enough times, `p[0]` is `None` and I get `WTH` to be printed out. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this runs:

```
timer = threading.Timer(timeout, lambda: kill_process(p))              
timer.start()
```

you launch a new thread.  The OS may then preempt your current thread and run the new thread for a while (or any other thread running on the system in other processes, for that matter).  If the system is very busy or you are very unlucky, it's possible that your thread is preempted for longer than `timeout`.  You should not start the timer until after you've populated `p[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a race condition.. You start the Timer (with the timeout) before you call Popen and set p[0] to a non-None value. If the subprocess doesn't setup and return the Popen object before the Timer fires you will see p[0] is None when you try to kill the process.

Make sure that your timeout value is high enough or wait until after you call Popen before starting the Timer.